# Are Backbone models supposed to be view-model, domain-models or both?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, models

Sorry if the question is vague but I am really having trouble finding information on this. I come from the Flex/ActionScript world where, for the most part, we have very simple Value Objects (VOs) to represent things like a User or an Address and we have Models that usually represented collections of those VOs along with business logic. There were some frameworks that would include a view model, MVVM. I know that there is no "right way" to do these things but I can't seem to point my finger on the basics.

Are all Backbone views supposed to have their own models? Given that I will likely not have a view called "User", would I also include domain models?

Would folders look something like this?

- App

  - models

    - domain

      - User
      - Address
    - view

      - UserProfileModel
  - views

    - UserProfileView
  - collections

    - Users

Again, sorry if this doesn't make sense or is too general. I am just trying to get an idea of how far along the JS world has gotten in terms of MVC patterns. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an only-one answer here. Every case will have an answer.

#### Are all Backbone views supposed to have their own models?

No.

There will be *Views* that will make reference to a *Model*, other ones will be making reference to a *Collection*. There will be also Views making reference to multiple Models, and others those will make reference to no-Model at all.

*A View is an User Interface. It shows data to the User and listen to the events the User trigger on this data representation.*

For example, if I have a Model called `Friend` and I want to create an interface to list a bunch of this Models I'll have:

- **FriendsView**: which is a *View* that represents a Collection of Friends.
- **FriendView**: which is a *sub-View* of FriendsView wich represent only one Friend. It can also listen to the `click` on the *destroy* button for this Friend.

But also I'll want to have a form to search from Friends in my server:

- **FriendSearchView**: which not have reference to any Model or Collection. But is listening to the User filling an *input* field.

#### Would I also include domain models?

I don't know what do you mean with *domain models* but if you are asking about where to put the *business logic* Backbone is very agnostic about that. I recommend to put as much calculation as possible into the Models or Collections. Also you can use your own *pure JS* Util library.

Keep the Views clean. Only responding to User events and calling Model and Collection methods as needed. Also listening in changes in the Model or Collection from which it is showing the data.

#### How folders should look like?

Well, Backbone is again agnostic about this. There are a lot of literature about this.

My projects use to be small, less than 30 files. I put all of them in the same folder with a naming convection like this:

- Friend
- Friends
- FriendView
- FriednsView

Comment: Thanks for your well thought out reply. A lot of examples and tutorials assumed a every view had a model. The way you are describing/using models is how I envision them as well in that they represent real-world business entities or "domain model". However, there can also be a "view model" which represents all the data and methods a single view needs to render/function. But couldn't your Friend model then have to have logic for both the FriendsView and the FriendView even though that logic might be specific to one or the other? Do you ever run into issue with this?

Comment: @TonySmith if the logic is more related to a _Friends_ as a collection I rather put the logic in the _Backbone.Collection_. For example: _filters_, or any elements batch manipulation. After this we could move to study more specific examples.

Comment: OK. Honestly I have not really researched the role Collections play in the MVC architecture. I will check that out but you have given me enough to get me started. Thanks fguillen.

Comment: @TonySmith don't try to match the academic description of MVC into Backbone paradigm.. they both don't match very well :). But sure: start playing and it will come to you.